# (wasm) pass an array between JS and C

Tags: webassembly

what should I be careful about regarding the security of the data transferring when I use linear memory in JS and pointers in C to pass an array between JS and C.

the same question when I pass an array between JS and C using pointers in C  and malloc , cwrap, getValue, setValue in JS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, but WebAssembly runs in a sandbox and has at most the same privileges as JavaScript. If you corrupt a module’s linear memory, it will have the same security implications as corrupt input would have for an arbitrary JavaScript function in your code.